# Tensorflow-gpu 2.3.1 cannot access GPU, NVIDIA GeForce MX150

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have both CPU and a GPU version of  tensorflow installed in Windows 10.

```
conda list t.*flow
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Dell\anaconda4:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu-estimator  2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Also, I have already installed CUDA and cuDNN by following the steps at this link  https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781  the only difference is that I downloaded the latest versions of CUDA and cuDNN to conform with the requirements of tensorflow 2.3.1 but still I could not access my GPU, which is a NVIDIA GeForce MX150.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
```

return True.

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
```

output:

WARNING:tensorflow:From :1: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.

False

Any thoughts as to why tensorflow 2.3.1 cannot access/find the GPU? Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: What's the full output of Tensorflow's log when you run a sample program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `tensorflow-gpu` does not require `tensorflow` in order to work, and by having both installed you may be importing the cpu version instead.

First uninstall the standard tensorflow and see if that fixes.

The NVIDIA GeForce MX150 does support CUDA, but there may still be compatibility issues with the most recent versions of tensorflow, CUDA and CUDNN.

The discusson [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-toolkit-9-is-not-available-in-geforce-mx150/53148/7) claims a working combination with with CUDA 9.1 and CUDNN 7.0.5. My advice would be to remove your installed versions and try these, though this will probably require a downgrade of tensorflow-gpu to make it compatible.

Comment: I tried uninstalling Tensorflow but the output is still the same. tensorflow-gpu can't find the gpu. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: is your GPU definitely in the list of [compatible](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) cards?

Comment: The model of my GPU is NVIDIA GeForce MX150. it is not on the list that you shared however, MX150 supports CUDA https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/gaming-laptops/geforce-mx150/specifications/

Comment: You could run in docker environment to avoid all this. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine. But I can tell you from experience that finding a working combination of drivers, cuda toolkit, cud-nn, tensorflow and python is frequently a pain and just because it should work doesn't mean it will. You don't seem to be alone, and on [this thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-toolkit-9-is-not-available-in-geforce-mx150/53148/7) people seem to have had success with    CUDA 9.1 and CUDNN 7.0.5. My advice would be to remove your installed versions and try these, though this will probably require a downgrade of tensorflow-gpu to make it compatible.

Comment: I see you green ticked, does that mean the versions I recommended fixed the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your warning showing that `tf.test.is_gpu_available` is deprecated. If you visit the tensorflow doc here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available. It is mentioned on the doc that this method to check the access to GPU is deprecated.

You should use `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')`.
To be more precise, use below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Your expected output should be as below if you have one GPU:

```
# Num GPUs Available:  1
```